# How to disable/enable combination keys (alt+space, alt+F10)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

How do I disable/enable combination keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>alt+F10</kbd>).

Comment: What are these keys shortcut for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default is used to **Activate the window menu**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> by default is used for **Toggle maximization state**

You can change or disable these shortcuts in **System Settings**.

In Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop:

[image: settings dialog]

To disable these shortcuts, just click on one of them and press the backspace key.

**For Ubuntu 16.04** the solution is same, but there is no defined default shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

[image: settings on unity]

Comment: It's not available in my ubuntu VM 16.04. Let me know any other alternative solution for it.

Comment: Activate the window menu was disabled but toggle maxmization state still working for me . I have disabled in  **System Settings**

Comment: Reset one shortcut doesn't disable another shortcut.
For disable "toggle maximization state" shortcut, reset it's value.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, here is how to disable it in Unity desktop manager on 18.04. The setting is only available in CompizConfig Configuration Manager.

```
sudo apt-get install -y compizconfig-settings-manager

sudo ccsm
```

Note that you may have to temporary setup python 2 as the default Python using update alternatives for it to launch.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

It's under Desktop -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

After changing set python back to Python 3 (if that's your default)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

[image]