# Where this Activate the window menu (Alt+space) in dconf locate?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dconf

By referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002077/773499), I have known where to disable these shortcuts in **System Settings**. But how can I disable through dconf.

I have tried:

```
dconf load / << EOF
[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
activate-window-menu='Disabled'
EOF
```

Is this the correct schema to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key? Please advice.